# How to unit test unexported private functions in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("fruit")
  function selectionChange(params) {
    console.log(params)
    setValue(params)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <select onChange={(e) => selectionChange(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>

          <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>

          <option value="meat">Meat</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How to test `selectionChange` function using Jest and React Testing Library in this case?
Do we have to mock useState and if so how to do that?

Comment: That function is called when the form data changes, so simulate a user input that changes the form data. But all it does is log, so there's not much interesting behaviour to assert on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Will you please elaborate with code?

Comment: Have a look at https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited my code with proper example, and I have reframed the questions your inputs will add value. Please do the needful.

Comment: No you don't mock useState. Don't mock what you don't own. Test _behaviour_, not implementation. But given your component doesn't really have any behaviour, value isn't even used, still all you can test us the right value for logged. But no I'm not writing tests for you.